# When would you use $_post instead of $post?

Tags: php, variables, loop

I've seen some examples that use $_post instead of $post. What's the difference and when would you use $_post instead of $post?

Example:

```
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if(!in_category("some-category", $_post )) { do_something(); }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not certain, but if you're talking about $_post as seen here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

It's referring to a post ID so they've probably added the underscore to avoid confusion. The $post variable is a post object with all the details of the post.

However, $_POST is a global PHP variable containing all the values sent from a form:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Exactly, now I remember where I got it from. Its puzzled me since. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 3):

> Q: When would you use $_post instead of $post?

Whenever I think it's applicable, for your example I have no idea.

> Q: What's the difference and when would you use $_post instead of $post?

The difference is that you are using different variables.

### Different variables

This is more or less a coding question, but I try to be as helpful as I can to answer it in the context of WordPress.

`$_post` is just a variable, the `$` identifies that it's a variable and `_post` is the variable's name. Those [names are case-sensitive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) btw., so `$_post` and `$_Post` or `$_POST` are all different variables. And `$post` for sure is as well.

If you want to learn what's in a variable - ie to find out more about it - you can make use of the [var_dump() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php): `var_dump($_post);`.

This can be helpful to find out more, because with the code you provided it can not be said for what the `$_post` variable stands for.

As variables can contain any value (incl. being even not set) you need to find the part of the code that is setting the variable.

### Special Meaning of `$post` in the loop

The variable `$post` has a special meaning in the context of [the_loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop): It contains a reference to the current post in the loop.

Comment: +1 thanks for taking the time to explain this. As Pabline noted, my reference came from the codex example for in_category, but your explanation helps paint the full picture.